# Redirection error (after certbot renewal / nginx)

Tags: php, nginx, redirect, configuration, certbot

This configuration for my webserver works partly (actual Ubuntu). If the newest Firefox uses the site with a smartphone, it results in a redirection error. Some other browsers may work, but not reliable. I tried to delete the browser cache and restarted/reloaded the nginx-server.
Is there an error in the NGINX-config? The problem first occurred, when I renewed the SSL certs with certbot. Thank you!

```
    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 ssl;
    
        # SSL configuration
        #
        # listen 443 ssl default_server;
        # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        #
        # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
        #
        # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
        #
        # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
        # Don't use them in a production server!
        #
        # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;    
    
        server_name sozcafe.de;     
        
        location / {
            root /var/www/html;
            index index.php;
            try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
        }
        
        location @rewrite {
            rewrite ^/(forum/|chat/|cms/|wcf/|calendar/|filebase/|blog/|gallery/)?([^.]+)$ /$1index.php?$2 last;
        }
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/sozcafe.de/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/sozcafe.de/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
        
        #ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.coffeecat.de/cert.pem;
        #ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.coffeecat.de/privkey.pem;
        
        # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
        #
        location ~ \.php$ {
            root /var/www/html;
            index index.php;
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;  
        
            
            
        #
        #   # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        #   # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
        #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        }
    
        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #   deny all;
        #}
    
    
    }
    
    server {
        
        server_name sozcafe.de www.sozcafe.de;
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
        
    
        listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
        listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/sozcafe.de/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/sozcafe.de/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
    
    
    }
    
    server {
        if ($host = www.sozcafe.de) {
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        } # managed by Certbot
    
    
        if ($host = sozcafe.de) {
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        } # managed by Certbot
    
    
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        
        server_name sozcafe.de www.sozcafe.de;
        return 404; # managed by Certbot
    
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking carefully in your config file you can figure out that you are listening  for the same port (`443`), the same server name (`sozcafe.de`) in two of your server blocks, the first and second one to be more specific. Having the statement `return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri` in the second server block of your config causes an effect of *"infinite loop"* because *nginx* always redirects to this server block each time you access to your domain.

I suspect Certbot added one of those when you ran it.

You can solve it by deleting `sozcafe.de` in your second server block to redirect only the `www` domain instead the target domain itself.

```
    server {
        
        # server_name sozcafe.de www.sozcafe.de;
        server_name www.sozcafe.de;
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
        
    
        listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
        listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/sozcafe.de/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/sozcafe.de/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
    
    
    }
```